# Scatterplot function for different attributes with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Let's say I have a dataframe `df`. (Below I use the example of `mtcars`.) Can I write a function that will take in any two attributes of the `df` and produce a ggplot2 scatterplot?

So far I have the following code:

```
scatterplotter <- function(att1, att2){
  plot <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=att1, y=att2)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(vs))) +
    xlab(paste(att1)) + ylab(paste(att2)) +
    ggtitle(paste("plot of",att1,"and ",att2))
return(plot)
}
```

Now I have the problem that, while `x=att1` and `y=att2` are as they should be, this is not going to work with the pastes, and I get an error saying `Error in parse(text = disp) : object 'disp' not found`. Can anyone help with this?

I wouldn't mind how the names are to be fed into the function, whether `scatterplotter("disp","gear")` or `scatterplotter(disp,gear)` for instance.

(No packages besides base-R + ggplot2 please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `aes_string()`

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
scatterplotter <- function(att1, att2){
  plot <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes_string(x=att1, y=att2)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(vs))) +
    xlab(paste(att1)) + ylab(paste(att2)) +
    ggtitle(paste("plot of",att1,"and ",att2))
  return(plot)
}

scatterplotter("mpg", "disp")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This does it